# python Popen print the output of the external application and save it (log it) at the same time

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run an external application using Popen and print the output in the console or separated console (better) and at the same time save the output to the file. There is no user interaction via console, **app.bat** just sends (writes) the data and should terminate automatically when the execution is finished.

Running the following command will result only in printing the results in the python console.

```
p = subprocess.Popen("app.bat --x --y", shell=False)
```

If I add stdout as file I can redirect the output to the file, but nothing is written in the console, which does not give users any feedback (and the feedback needs to be in real-time, not after the execution because app runs approximately 1-3min).

```
file_ = open("ouput.txt", "w+")
p = subprocess.Popen("app.bat --x --y", shell=False,stdout=file_)
```

Therefore, my question is how to run the external app and at the same time write in the console and in the file?

Comment: What stops you to `print()` the STDOUT from your process at the same time you're writing it to a file?

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do I'd encourage you to use the logging module.
A good starter here is https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html
It even describes your usecase almost exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post-process the output of your `Popen()` call, you should typically redirect `stdout` to `PIPE` and then read the output from there. This will allow you to e.g. both write to file and to screen:

```
import subprocess

logfile ='output.txt'
command = ['app.bat', '--x', '--y']

p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

with open(logfile, 'w+') as f:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line.rstrip())
        f.write(line)
```

Now, this will block until  `app.bat` finishes, which may be exactly what you want. But, if you want your Python script to continue to run, and have `app.bat` run in te background, you can start a thread that will handle your `subprocess` `stdout`:

```
import subprocess
import threading

logfile ='output.txt'
command = ['app.bat', '--x', '--y']

def writer(p, logfile):
    with open(logfile, 'w+') as f:
        for line in p.stdout:
            print(line.rstrip())
            f.write(line)

p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

t = threading.Thread(target=writer, args=(p,logfile))
t.start()

# Other commands while app.bat runs

t.join()
```